# Custom Delegate Callback

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm facing a problem
I'm having a problem with custom delegate.
I'm trying to make a simple custom where it return data to the previous view controller and pop the current view controller.

I have 2 navigation view controller

1 - main view controller
2 - Adding

and here is the protocol that is written in the adding view controller

```
@protocol AddingDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)setInformation:(Adding *)controller withObject:(Conference *)info;
```

and here is the where I called it in adding view controller

```
-(IBAction)addingConference
{
    NSLog(@"Adding Button Pressed");
    conferenceObject = [[Conference alloc]init];
    conferenceObject.name = [NameTX text];
    conferenceObject.city = [CityTX text];
    conferenceObject.description = [Dectription text];
    NSMutableArray *info = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [info addObject:conferenceObject];
    [self.delegate setInformation:self withObject:conferenceObject];
    NSLog(@"adding Conference method is done");
}
```

I wrote the delegate at the interface in the main view controller

```
@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <AddingDelegate>

@end
```

and here where I declared the delegate method

```
-(void)setInformation:(Adding *)controller withArray:(NSMutableArray *)info
{
    NSLog(@"in the main view at the delegate");
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Should be popped right now");
}
```

and this is the prepare for segue method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddObject"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigation = segue.destinationViewController;
        Adding *addingViewController = [[navigation viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        addingViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

now the problem is when I push the adding on top of the stack and then fill the information and press done the adding view controller doesn't pop to show main view controller.

I tried to log everything and the logs from the main view controller doesn't show .

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I notice here is that in the implementation of `prepareForSegue:sender:` the segue's `destinationViewController` is a navigation controller. This makes me think that your segue is not pushing the `AddingController` on the current navigation stack but it's presenting a new one instead. This means the new navigation controller containing the `AddingController` is presented modally and as such, when you try to pop the navigation stack nothing seems to happen because you're operating on the wrong navigation stack. If that is the case you have two options: 1. change `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` for `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` or 2. change the segue to be a push segue instead of a modal segue and point the segue directly to the `AddingController`.

Comment: I did the two options you mentioned and the segue is push segue and nothing changed instead now it shows an error that I sent an invalid selector

Comment: Are you actually pushing a new navigation controller from the first? If so why? That's probably messing up the self.navigationController property values. If removing the second navigation controller doesn't help, put a breakpoint in the method that calls the AddingController delegate. Run the app and when the breakpoint is hit try to figure out if the delegate is correctly set, if it's receiving the message, what is the navigation controller's status, etc. until you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Adding.m

```
  @class Adding;

@protocol AddingDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface Adding : UIViewController

 @property (weak, nonatomic) id <AddingDelegate> delegate; // have you forgot this one


 @end
```

and use

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

You need dismiss if you want get back to previous screen and make sure you have added Navigation controller
[image: Your storyboard should look like this]